# How can I increase the range of Windows 10 volume?

Tags: windows-10, audio, volume-mixer, equalizer

I'm using Equalizer APO to reduce -20dB because I had been using my headphones at between 4-10 volume (in windows so out of 100). Which has made it a lot better.

But sometimes certain videos or games or whatever just seem to be very quiet for whatever reason, even when Windows is set to 100. Obviously I could change the preamp in Equalizer but then that would leave me with the same issue as before.

What I would like to do is be able to set windows to higher than 100. Is there some way to unlock the controls so I can set it up to say 200?

Failing that can I use Equalizer or some other program to set a kind of curve, so if I'm under 30 in windows then the -20db should kick in, if I'm between 30 and 60 then it should be -10db and if over 60 then no reduction. (Obviously a smoother curve would be nicer if at all possible).

Comment: What you're looking for is dynamic compression.  I'm curious though why your headphone volume is good for you at 4-10%.  Are you using some headphone amplifier downstream from your computer?  If so, it would be better to adjust the volume there when possible.

Comment: Nope I don't have anything, I've tried my headphones on other devices so I guess they're just made loud? probably most people like it really loud these days haha.

Comment: How do your headphones connect?  Normal 1/8" stereo jack?  USB?  Bluetooth?

Comment: they use a USB cable

Answer (score 1):

Too much for a comment, not enough for an answer…

If your headphones connect via USB, then they contain a DAC & an amp. As Brad mentions in comments, what you need is a compressor/limiter of some sort in your output chain. It's not possible to go over '100' [though100 is just an arbitrary consumer number] Inside the signal path is a value measured in dBFS [decibels, full-scale] which starts at -60 or lower & **rises** to 0 [zero]. This zero value cannot be exceeded; there are simply *'no more numbers left'* at that point.

The Equaliser APO structure mentions it can use VST plugins - so I'd suggest searching for a freeware compressor/limiter. Test single- & multi-band versions until you find one you like.
You might also need to read up on some background theory on compression; it's not rocket science, but you'll find it easier if you have a bit of a grounding first.

I'd also have a look at things like the Peace interface for the EQAPO & Voicemeeter to see if either of them can support values per output channel.
I can't test any of this, I'm not on Windows.]